# How can I make my FBX model rotate using animate function?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to make my FBX model rotate continuously using three.js.

So I tried

1. make my object into variable
2. call my object in animate function to rotate. (girl1)

but I got an error:

> Cannot read property 'rotation' of undefined.

My code is like this:

```js
function init() {
    ...

    // zombie girl

    let loader_girl = new FBXLoader();

    loader_girl.load("ZombiePunching.fbx", (object) => {
        // animation mixer
        mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(object);

        const action = mixer.clipAction(object.animations[0]);
        action.play();

        // make materials opaque
        object.traverse((child) => {
            if (child.isMesh) {
                child.material.transparent = false;
            }
        });

        object.scale.set(0.05, 0.05, 0.05);
        object.rotation.x = Math.PI;
        scene.add(object);

        girl1 = object;
    });

    ...
    let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load("smoke.png", function (texture) {
        let cloudGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(500, 500);
        let cloudMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            map: texture,
            transparent: true,
        });
        for (let p = 0; p < 25; p++) {
            let cloud = new THREE.Mesh(cloudGeo, cloudMaterial);
            cloud.position.set(
                Math.random() * 800 - 400,
                500,
                Math.random() * 500 - 450
            );
            cloud.rotation.x = 1.16;
            cloud.rotation.y = -0.12;
            cloud.rotation.z = Math.random() * 360;
            cloud.material.opacity = 0.6;
            cloudParticles.push(cloud);
            scene.add(cloud);
        }
    });
}

function animate() {
    cloudParticles.forEach((p) => {
        p.rotation.z -= 0.002;
    });

    rainGeo.vertices.forEach((p) => {
        p.velocity -= 0.1 + Math.random() * 0.1;
        p.y += p.velocity;
        if (p.y < -200) {
            p.y = 200;
            p.velocity = 0;
        }
    });
    rainGeo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    rain.rotation.y += 0.002;

    girl1.rotation.y += 0.001;

    if (Math.random() > 0.93 || flash.power > 100) {
        if (flash.power < 100)
            flash.position.set(Math.random() * 400, 300 + Math.random() * 200, 100);
        flash.power = 50 + Math.random() * 500;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
animate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```js
girl1.rotation.y += 0.001;
```

try it with:

```js
if ( girl1 ) girl1.rotation.y += 0.001;
```

Since you start the animation loop *before* the FBX is actually loaded, `girl1` will be `undefined` for a certain amount of time.